# How to install Firewatir

Tags: watir, firewatir

I tried to install firewatir, and got the following error. I would be grateful for assistance.

```
C:\>gem install firewatir
Successfully installed firewatir-1.9.4
option --accessor is deprecated: support discontinued
file 'def_wrap=R,def_wrap_guard=R,def_creator=R,def_creator_with_default=R' not found
Installing ri documentation for firewatir-1.9.4
1 gem installed
```

Comment: By the way - your installation succeeded. There's no error message for the installation itself, only for generating the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firewatir has been deprecated. You should use watir-webdriver instead, which can control chrome, firefox and others.

To install:

```
gem install watir-webdriver
```

To use:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox # Will open a firefox browser
```

Note that if you use the watir gem, it supports both IE (using watir-classic) and other browsers (using watir-webdriver). I believe both gems are installed if you did `gem install watir`. This means you can do:

```
require 'watir'

# If you want to use Firefox
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

# If you want to use IE
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
```

If you do not specify a browser the default will be IE on windows and Firefox on other platforms.